# flex autocomplete change/textEvent not fired

Tags: apache-flex, autocomplete

I am trying to make flex [autocomplete](http://hillelcoren.com/flex-autocomplete/comment-page-6/) change its dataprovider at runtime based on user input.

```
    <components:AutoComplete  change="change()" id="ac" dataProvider="{_a1}" width="100" />
    <s:Button label="change" click="change()" />
    private function change():void
        {
            Alert.show("sdsd");
            //Alert.show(event.text);
            //ac.dataProvider = _a2;
        }
```

when I click the button, the function get fired, but when i input the text, it doesnt fire.
I was trying to use both change and textEvent, however, none of them are fired. 
I wonder if there is any way that i can do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no AutoComplete component in the Flex SDK. So which one are you talking about?

Comment: @RIAstar:sorry, just added the component link

Comment: seems when there is a match, and the match is selected, the event is fired. still wonder if I want to fire the event when the user input is not matched, what need to be done.

Comment: I don't know Hillel's implementation very well; but I would not expect the change event to fire unless a new item is selected.  Typing new characters into an AutoComplete is not the same as selecting a new item.  If the component exposes it; you may be able to listen for a change event directly on the TextInput.